Embed iframe tag in Content Hub Rich Text Editor
I am trying to embed the iframe tag into the Content Hub Rich Text Editor using internal Integration via script.
The script replaces the placeholder key with an iframe tag in the Rich Text Editor field, and this functionality is working correctly. When the save event is triggered, the script executes successfully, embedding the video as intended.
Sample Code Snippet:
var videoUrl = $"https://players.brightcove.net/1752604059001/HJSEihoR_default/index.html?videoId=5165694790001";
var fieldContentBody = entity.GetPropertyValue<string>("description");
string placehoderKey = "{video-1}";
if (fieldContentBody.Contains(placehoderKey))
{
isReplaced = true;
var iframeTag = $"<iframe src=\"{videoUrl}\" width=\"{width}\" height=\"{height}\"></iframe>";
fieldContentBody = fieldContentBody.Replace(placehoderKey, bcIframe);
}

There is no issue with Script and it successfully embeds the iframe tag and I can see the video in data.
However, when I click into the description field to update any content, the video disappears. I need to re-enter the placeholder key or refresh the page to see the video again.
Is there any issue with embedding iframe I can see if I replace the same with the H1 tag and text it does not appear.
I see if we add a YouTube video using the OOTB feature it also creates an iframe and does not disappear.
PS: The Video source URL is not a YouTube video and CMP module.

I tested this script on my side, its working as intended in the Content Hub latest version...on which version you are getting this issue...Moreover can you also tell what will be the value inside the bcIframe variable..

@ckhanna value I am using 'https://players.brightcove.net/1752604059001/HJSEihoR_default/index.html?videoId=5165694790001' question has been updated.

I checked on Content Hub DAM..This is working perfectly fine there..May be there is some issue in CKEditor version inside CMP. You can raise Sitecore ticket to get it checked.

After investigating more and checking with the Sitecore support team:
Sitecore Team determined that the issue arises because CKEditor, which is the rich text field editor we use, employs content filtering or sanitization. This is a security measure designed to prevent issues such as XSS attacks. Due to Brightcove not being on the list of supported sources, CKEditor automatically removes the iframe tags when a user attempts to edit the existing content.
For more information, we may refer to the following resources:

sanitizeHtml documentation
List of supported media providers

